# Is there a way to show the last picture on this slideshow using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

My code so far loops through 3/4 or 2/3 items. These items are in an array. The last picture says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at HTMLElement". 
There are two classes for showing the picture and turning off the picture: "on" and "off" respectively.
Code for HTML:

```
            <div class="first off">
                <img src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/sunrise-sunset-sun-calculator.jpg?1" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="second off">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSvLhLs2n6RpRIksOmhqH40yt88fgGcAC6uGlWENi3_WGWfXeoa&usqp=CAU" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="thrird off">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512149448423-de868c37fbab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=2000&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExNzczfQ" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="last off">
                <img src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/sunrise-sunset-sun-calculator.jpg?1" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Code for Javascript:

```
var index = 0

arrow.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    var slide = divs[index]
    index++

    if (index >= divs.length) {
        index = 0
        for (let i = 0; i <= divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].classList.replace("on", "off")
        }
    }

    slide.classList.replace("off", "on")
    log(index + slide)
})
```

**Note: I did look at a few questions similar to this question(?) but they were in JQuery**

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: if you can put this in to a fiddle with relevant css (https://jsfiddle.net/), it will be easy for people to help you

Comment: add `-1`  to ``<= divs-length`` or use `forEach` to iterate your ``divs``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add another checker and it worked fine

```
    var slide = divs[index]
    index++

    if (index >= divs.length) {
        index = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].classList.replace("on", "off")
        }
    }
    //this was needed
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].classList.replace("on", "off")
    }
    //
    slide.classList.replace("off", "on")

    log(index + slide)
```

Thanks for the people who responded back!

Answer (score 0):

Since array indexes start with zero, your `for` loop should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem? It seems likely that's the line that's causing the error, but you could be having other issues.

Comment: It works, I already tried it but, when it restarts from the beginning, one picture overlaps the other.

Answer (score 0):

The Error says, that it is trying to read a property of undefined. The undefined tells you that it is looking for something that doesn't exist.

As it affects the last picture, it can be assumed that the loop running through the array is running to often by one.

The array.length gives you the number of elements inside your array.
But you are using the indexes of the array in div[i]. Because the first element of an array is addressed by the index of 0, your for loop has to run one time less than the number of elements in the array.

So in the for loop, it has to be  i < divs.length instead of your i <= divs.length